# Difference in type between using and not using Set keyword

Tags: vba

I just solved a problem I was having putting the "Set" keyword in a definition line but what I would like to know is "why" ?

Basically, I am doing this:

```
Dim startCell, iCell as Range
For Each iCell in Range(whatever)
    If iCell.value <>"" Then
        Set startCell = Cells(iCell.Row + 1, iCell.Column)
    End If
Next iCell
```

If I omit the "Set" keyword the code still compiles fine, but in the local variables window I see that its *type* changes to "String" instead of "Variant/Object/Range". Why would that happen ?

Comment: startCell isn't of Range type here...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is why. When you say this:

```
Dim startCell, iCell As Range
```

you *think* you've done this:

```
Dim startCell As Range, iCell As Range
```

but what you've *really* done is this:

```
Dim startCell 'As Variant, by default
Dim iCell As Range
```

This is a classic VBA mistake. Most VBA programmers have made it, and that's why most VBA programmers fall back on declaring only one variable per `Dim` statement (i.e. one per line). Otherwise it's way too easy to make that mistake, and difficult to spot it afterwards.

So with `Dim startCell` you've implicitly declared your variable as Variant type (equivalent to `Dim startCell As Variant`).

When you then say this:

```
Set startCell = Cells(iCell.Row + 1, iCell.Column)
```

the Variant acquires the type of the thing on the right hand side of the reference assignment (Range). However, when you say this:

```
startCell = Cells(iCell.Row + 1, iCell.Column)
```

without the `Set` keyword, you're not assigning a reference, but a value to the variable `startCell`, which now acquires the type of the value on the right hand side. What is that type? Well, the default property of a Range object is `Value`, so you're going to get the type of `Cells(iCell.Row + 1, iCell.Column).Value`. If that cell contains a string, then you'll get a string.

Answer (score 3):

`Set` is used to assign a reference to an object, `Let` (or simple assignment) to assign the value of an object (if any)

```
  Dim a As Variant
  Set a = ActiveSheet.Cells(1)
  'TypeName(a) = Range, a now contains reference to the cell's range
  a = ActiveSheet.Cells(1)
  'TypeName(a) = Double or String, whatever is in the Cell, a contains the cell's value
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the **Set** keyword when assigning an object to a variable.  `Cells(iCell.Row + 1, iCell.Column)` is returning a **Range** object, thus **Set** must be used, otherwise you will get everyone's favorite VBA error: `91: Object variable or With block variable not set`.

Edit:

Range objects have a default return property as well, which is the 'Value' property.  If you were to just reference Range("A1") it would take that ranges 'Value' as default for a variant.  This is why you should avoid using variants when the data type is known ahead of time.

Comment: ... yet, as he says in the question, he is not getting that error. Why? That's what makes this question interesting.