# How to convert currency into double in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have three textboxes and I get their value like this:

```
Dim X, Y, W As Double
X = DLookup("Summ", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
Y = DLookup("Deposit_before", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
W = DLookup("Monthly_payment", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
```

But when I change the value of textbox like this

```
Form_frmPlatej.Deposit_before = X - W + Y
```

I get a Type mismatch error. All textboxes are currency. How do I calculate new record and put that number in the "Deposit_before" textbox?

Summ, Deposit_before, Monthly_payment are currency data type in my table. Deposit_before is mostly negative.

Here is my whole code for button click

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()

a1 = DLookup("Inhabitant", "tblClient", "ID = " & Form_frmMain!ID)
B1 = DLookup("PriceTBO", "tblPrice")
c1 = DLookup("Republican", "tblClient", "ID = " & Form_frmMain!ID)
d1 = DLookup("Regional", "tblClient", "ID = " & Form_frmMain!ID)
e1 = DLookup("Local", "tblClient", "ID = " & Form_frmMain!ID)

A = DLookup("IDP", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
B = DLookup("Type_of_payment", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
C = DLookup("Year", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
D = DLookup("Month", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)

Y = DLookup("Deposit_before", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID) // Problem here
W = DLookup("Monthly_payment", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID) //Problem here
X = DLookup("Summ", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)

i = Form_frmPlatej.Month.ListIndex
j = Form_frmPlatej.Year.ListIndex
den = DLookup("Date", "tblPlatej", "IDP = " & Form_frmPlatej!IDP)

If X <> " " Then
With Me.Recordset
If Me.Recordset.BOF = False And Me.Recordset.EOF = False Then
.MoveFirst
End If
.AddNew
.Edit

Form_frmPlatej.Deposit_before = X - W + Y  //Problem here

Form_frmPlatej.IDP = A + 1
Form_frmPlatej.Type_of_payment = B
If i = 11 Then
Form_frmPlatej.Year = Year.ItemData(j + 1)
i = -1
Else
Form_frmPlatej.Year = Year.ItemData(j)
End If

Form_frmPlatej.Month = Month.ItemData(i + 1)
Form_frmPlatej.Date = DateAdd("m", 1, den)

If c1 <> 0 Then
Form_frmPlatej.Monthly_payment = (a1 * B1) - (c1 * (a1 * B1)) / 100

ElseIf d1 <> 0 Then
Form_frmPlatej.Monthly_payment = (a1 * B1) - (d1 * (a1 * B1)) / 100

ElseIf e1 <> 0 Then
Form_frmPlatej.Monthly_payment = (a1 * B1) - (e1 * (a1 * B1)) / 100
Else
Form_frmPlatej.Monthly_payment = a1 * B1
End If
.Update

End With

Else
MsgBox ("Please enter number")
End If

End Sub
```

I am completely confused.

Comment: I am curious as to why you wish to convert to double from currency? Why not work with the currency type when that is what you have? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet your problem is the following. When you say this:

```
Dim X, Y, W As Double
```

you *think* you've done this:

```
Dim X As Double, Y As Double, W As Double
```

but what you've *really* done is this:

```
Dim X
Dim Y
Dim W As Double
```

This is a classic VBA mistake. Most VBA programmers have made it, and that's why most VBA programmers fall back on declaring only one variable per `Dim` statement (i.e. one per line). Otherwise it's way too easy to make that mistake, and difficult to spot it afterwards.

So with `Dim X` and `Dim Y` you've implicitly declared `X` and `Y` as Variant type (equivalent to `Dim X As Variant` and `Dim Y As Variant`).

Why does this matter? When you then say this:

```
X = DLookup("Summ", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
Y = DLookup("Deposit_before", "tblPlatej", "ID= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)
```

maybe one of those two `DLookup` unexpectedly returns something that isn't a number, for example a string. Your variant `X` or `Y` will accept this without complaining; the Variant acquires the type of the thing on the right hand side of the assignment.

However, when you try to do math with these values, `X - W + Y` will throw a type mismatch error if `X` and/or `Y` is a string.

See also this earlier answer of mine, from which I reused some of the wording: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089684/119775

Comment: I tried to declare explicitly                                     Dim X As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim W As Double
Dim Z As Double                                                        The same error occurs...

Comment: On what line? When the error occurs, what are the values of `X`, `Y` and `W` in the debug window?

Comment: Summ, Deposit_before, Monthly_payment are currency data type in my table. Deposit_before is mostly negative. Error in this line Y = DLookup("[Deposit_before]", "tblPlatej", "[ID]= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID)

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov When you encounter that error, switch to debug mode, and run this in the Immediate window: `? TypeName(DLookup("[Deposit_before]", "tblPlatej", "[ID]= " & Form_frmPlatej!ID))`  If the response is Null and Y has been declared as Double, you have a type mismatch.

Comment: Yes it is NULL, Why Deposit_before is null? It means Dlookup is not working?

Comment: It is returning now string... I am absolutely confused

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I guessed in my answer yesterday: "*`DLookup` unexpectedly returns [...] a string.*" Perhaps you should accept this answer and ask a new question that is more specific to your new problem.